# ACPI errors prevent boot after upgrade to kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, kubuntu, acpi

I get a few ACPI errors each time I boot. They increase until booting does not complete.

- I tried upgrading from 16.04 and a fresh install of 18.04
- It works with acpi=off in grub, but then I dont get battery status for my notebook.
- I contacted the machine's vendor about a BIOS upgrade. pcspecialist unhelpfully replied saying they dont support ubuntu and they dont have any BIOS updates for my chassis.

dmidecode excerpt

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 5.11
    Release Date: 09/10/2015
```

dmesg | grep ACPI

```
[    4.086951] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer]         (ptrval) (20170831/exresop-103)
[    4.087913] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    4.089113] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    4.282402] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000000ea1c204 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    4.282406] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    4.282413] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    4.482337] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000002eca52b7 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    4.482343] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    4.482353] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    4.683911] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000000ea1c204 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    4.683918] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    4.683927] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    4.883417] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000002eca52b7 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    4.883424] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    4.883433] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    5.083506] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000000ea1c204 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    5.083515] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    5.083525] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    5.284894] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000002eca52b7 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    5.284901] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    5.284909] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    5.530774] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000000ea1c204 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    5.530799] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    5.530817] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    5.687032] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    5.687040] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    5.687049] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    5.889577] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    5.889585] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    5.889594] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    6.088541] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    6.088558] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    6.088572] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    6.288504] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    6.288511] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    6.288520] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    6.489788] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    6.489794] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    6.489803] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    6.689683] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    6.689690] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    6.689699] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    6.889643] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    6.889658] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    6.889670] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    7.090986] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    7.090993] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    7.091001] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    7.290955] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    7.290962] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    7.290971] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    7.491036] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    7.491044] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    7.491053] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    7.692715] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    7.692722] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    7.692731] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    7.892186] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    7.892193] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    7.892202] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    8.093375] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    8.093382] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    8.093391] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    8.291250] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    8.291258] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    8.291268] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    8.490985] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    8.491015] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    8.491062] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    8.692368] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    8.692399] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    8.692446] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    8.890123] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    8.890153] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    8.890201] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    9.089790] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    9.089821] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    9.089869] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    9.289847] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    9.289884] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    9.289943] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    9.491373] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    9.491403] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    9.491450] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    9.691052] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[    9.691082] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    9.691129] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[    9.890967] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[    9.891005] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[    9.891064] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   10.092668] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   10.092699] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   10.092746] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   10.292090] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   10.292122] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   10.292170] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   10.493396] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   10.493427] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   10.493475] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   10.691203] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   10.691234] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   10.691281] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   10.890616] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   10.890653] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   10.890711] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   11.090695] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   11.090726] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   11.090772] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   11.292413] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   11.292445] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   11.292491] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   11.495215] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   11.495251] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   11.495284] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   11.691756] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   11.691786] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   11.691831] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   11.893066] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   11.893090] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   11.893131] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   12.092627] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   12.092655] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   12.092696] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   12.292480] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   12.292503] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   12.292543] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   12.491554] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   12.491578] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   12.491618] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   12.691229] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   12.691261] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   12.691321] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   12.891195] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   12.891225] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   12.891269] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   13.092872] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   13.092903] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   13.092949] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   13.292529] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   13.292559] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   13.292606] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   13.492581] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   13.492618] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   13.492677] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   13.694156] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   13.694187] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   13.694234] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   13.893523] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   13.893559] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   13.893616] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   14.093514] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   14.093544] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   14.093590] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   14.296814] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   14.296852] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   14.296910] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   14.496431] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   14.496469] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   14.496527] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   14.695037] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000006906065e (20170831/exresop-103)
[   14.695067] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[   14.695114] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._Q50, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
[   14.896345] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000d6868236 (20170831/exresop-103)
[   14.896383] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
```

- 16.04 has get less than a year of maintenance, so I dont want to go back to that.
- I am not sure if a BIOS upgrade direct from AMI is wise or possible.

Some similar issues mention nvidia GPUs. I have intel.

excerpt from glxinfo

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)  (0x1916)
    Version: 18.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Fedora 28 (using kernel 4.17.19) is tolerant of the buggy BIOS. I have rebooted several times over a few days, and the machine is still working well. I still see ACPI errors, but they dont stop the machine working.

```
dmesg | grep ACPI
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004274f000-0x000000004274ffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000873cb000-0x00000000873fcfff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000873fd000-0x0000000087baefff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F05B0 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000873D50A0 0000C4 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000873F2300 00010C (v05 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000873D51F8 01D105 (v02 ALASKA A M I    01072009 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x0000000087BAEF80 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000873F2410 000084 (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000873F2498 000044 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FIDT 0x00000000873F24E0 00009C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000873F2580 00003C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000873F25C0 000038 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI. 0005000B)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F25F8 000315 (v01 SataRe SataTabl 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LPIT 0x00000000873F2910 000094 (v01 INTEL  SKL-ULT  00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F29A8 000248 (v02 INTEL  sensrhub 00000000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F2BF0 002BAE (v02 INTEL  PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F57A0 000C45 (v02 INTEL  Ther_Rvp 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DBGP 0x00000000873F63E8 000034 (v01 INTEL           00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DBG2 0x00000000873F6420 000054 (v00 INTEL           00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F6478 000499 (v02 INTEL  xh_rvp07 00000000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MSDM 0x00000000873F6918 000055 (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873F6970 0053B0 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000873FBD20 000042 (v01                 00000000      00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000873FBD68 000E58 (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000873FCBC0 0000A8 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: ASF! 0x00000000873FCC68 0000A5 (v32 INTEL   HCG     00000001 TFSM 000F4240)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20180313
[    0.026007] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x4274f000-0x4274ffff] (4096 bytes)
[    0.026008] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x873fd000-0x87baefff] (8069120 bytes)
[    0.026403] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.026403] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.026403] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.028046] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.028047] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.028047] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.028048] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.028049] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.052808] ACPI: 8 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.057089] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.059945] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.059950] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069FB2800 000660 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.060303] ACPI: \_PR_.CPU0: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.061196] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.061200] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C406993C000 00037F (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20120913)
[    0.061510] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.061512] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069FD1A80 00008E (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.061735] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.061738] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069820A00 000130 (v02 PmRef  HwpLvt   00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.062519] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.062523] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069FB5800 0005AA (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.063000] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.063004] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069820800 000119 (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.063291] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.063294] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8C4069820E00 000119 (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.065110] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.065111] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.158363] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 0000000049ae6c95 (20180313/exresop-69)
[    0.158441] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [OpcodeName unavailable] (20180313/dswexec-427)
[    0.158522] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._REG, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.158606] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: Used as first EC
[    0.158607] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: GPE=0x50, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.158608] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions
[    0.158608] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.158642] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.158643] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.158674] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.159091] ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.161000] ACPI: Power Resource [PG00] (on)
[    0.161260] ACPI: Power Resource [PG01] (on)
[    0.161503] ACPI: Power Resource [PG02] (on)
[    0.162539] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.162794] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.163045] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.163299] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.163546] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.163794] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.164051] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.164307] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.164559] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.164816] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.165069] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.165327] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.165574] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.165825] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.166073] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.166320] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.166570] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.166824] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.167078] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.167334] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (off)
[    0.173769] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
[    0.173821] ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
[    0.173870] ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
[    0.173917] ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
[    0.173966] ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
[    0.174798] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe])
[    0.195153] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195194] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.195233] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195272] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195311] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195350] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195389] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195427] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.195859] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.195894] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.195909] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: GPE=0x50, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.195911] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions and events
[    0.196108] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.196108] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.237460] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.238907] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.238942] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD043b PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.239081] system 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.239154] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.239180] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.239360] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.239394] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.239622] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.240504] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.240979] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices
[    0.652816] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (off-line)
[    0.652867] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    0.652898] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.652922] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    0.652946] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.652983] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PENV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.653085] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN00._ON, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.653185] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PENV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.653263] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN00._ON, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.654176] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PLMX], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.654256] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZ00._TMP, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.654401] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PLMX], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.654479] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZ00._TMP, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.654832] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PECH], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.655199] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZ01._TMP, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.655551] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.PECH], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
[    0.655877] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZ01._TMP, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
[    0.894461] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    3.568125] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   33.158719] topstar_laptop: ACPI extras driver loaded
```

This might be the relevant difference between ubuntu 18.04 and fedora 28

```
[    0.057089] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```